# How do I customize GRUB to choose enter the text mode or enter the graphical mode

Tags: boot, grub2, text-mode

How do I customize GRUB so every time booting I could choose whether I want to boot into text mode or boot into graphical mode.

I have try to edit `/etc/default/grub` and change

`GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"` into `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="text"`

and update the GRUB, but this only change the boot mode into text, and I need to change it again if I want to boot into graphical mode. I know I can use startx from terminal to enter the graphical mode, but it's not answered my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use the `40_custom` file for this, preferably in maintenance mode.

**All commands in this tutorial are to be run as root! This tutorial also DOES NOT WORK for systems with `/boot` on a different partition!**

1. Find the UUID of your main partition by using `blkid` and looking for an EXT4 partition. Remember this UUID, you will need it soon.
2. Start by opening the 40_custom file.

```
nano /etc/grub.d/40_custom
```

3. Append this to the end of the file:

```
menuentry "Ubuntu Text Mode" {
     recordfail
     gfxmode $linux_gfx_mode
     insmod gzio
     insmod part_msdos
     insmod ext2
     set root='(hd0,msdos9)'
     search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root [UUID from earlier]
     linux /vmlinuz root=UUID=[UUID from earlier] ro text $vt_handoff
     initrd /initrd.img
}
```

4. Save this file as `15_custom`. It will be after the Ubuntu default entries. Name it to `06_custom` if you want it before default Ubuntu.
5. Run the following command, based on your system:

   ```
   chmod a+x /etc/grub.d/06_custom
   chmod a+x /etc/grub.d/15_custom
   ```
6. Finally, run this command to refresh the GRUB menu:

   ```
   update-grub
   ```

<sup>Source for this tutorial is available [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/CustomMenus), free of charge.</sup>

Comment: I am using `blkid` but it returns no value, can I use the value from `/etc/fstab` ?

Comment: @firmanium Sure.